# Java: Use component with name from variable

Tags: java, variables, components, jlabel

I just wanna know if there's a way to do something like this:

I have 100 jLabel ( jLabel1, jLabel2 ... jLabel100 ) and i have a int variable ( 32 ). I wanna use the Label with the variable name ( jLabel32 ) and do something with it. How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make a list ? plz describe what you wont to do with it.

Comment: i wanna set a different text in every jLabel

Comment: if you are trying to do something like this:
for int i, 1 to 100:
JLabel jLabel+i = new instanciation of JLabel class

you should look into java reflection